# Проверить элемент на котором фокус на пустоту

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как узнать, является ли элемент, на котором в данный момент фокус - пустым ?
Элемент находится внутри contenteditable блока. Не понимаю как проверить т.к. внутри элемента обычно ставится тег `<br>`.

Пробовал через `activeelement, is(:focus), trim` и т.п..не получается. Фокус ставится на contenteditable блок, а не на элементе внутри него, по которому я щелкнул. Подскажите, как поступить

```js
$('#article').on('keydown keyup click',function(e) {

    console.log(e.target);
    // console.log(e.target.textContent == '');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="article" contenteditable="true">
<p class="paragraph" >Параграф 1</p>
<p class="paragraph" >Параграф 2</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Минимальный код, чтобы воспроизвести поведение и проблему.

Comment: @UModeL добавил. При фокусе мышкой работает корректно, при Enter, стрелочки и любая другая кнопка - не работает. Фокус ставится на article

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дали на js [форуме](https://javascript.ru). Спасибо им за это. Собственно решение. Может кому-то понадобится:

```
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    let el = sel.focusNode;   // скорее всего получим текстовый узел, а не элемент
    if (el.nodeType != 1) el = el.parentElement; // тогда получаем родительский элемент.
    console.log(el.textContent == '');
```

Answer (score -1):

Как то так?, если нужно дополнение дай знать.
Если элемент пусто то при фокусе всплывает текст
и то же самое всплывает тогда когда все удаляешь из элемента

```js
let x = document.querySelector(".input")
document.querySelector(".input").oninput = function(){
  if(x.value == ""){
  x.placeholder = "Тут пусто";
  }

}
document.querySelector(".input").onfocus = function(){
  if(x.value == ""){
  x.placeholder = "Тут пусто";
  }
}
 document.querySelector(".input").onblur = function(){
  if(x.value == ""){
  x.placeholder = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" class = "input">
```